# Validate the date format of an "java.util.Date "with Bean validation

Tags: java, validation, date, javabeans, date-format

i have the following Code:

```
@Document
public class MyBean {
...
    @DateTimeFormat(iso = DateTimeFormat.ISO.DATE_TIME)
    @NotNull
    private Date theDate;

    @NotBlank
    private String aField;
...
}
```

When i post a valid date format the server returns an 400 Bad Request and my errormessages and filds as json in the body:

```
{
  "aField": null,
  "theDate":"2011-07-11T121:28:59.564+01:00",
}
```

Now when i post an invalid date format (no DateTimeFormat.ISO.DATE_TIME) the server returns *only* an 400 Bad Request without validation and error messages in the body.:

```
{
  "aField": null,
  "theDate":"invalid format",
}
```

How can i validate the date format of the "java.uti.date" field?

Here is my Controller Code:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/foo")
public class MyController {
    ...
    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public ResponseEntity createMyBean(@RequestBody @Valid MyBean myBean, BindingResult result) {
    ...
}
```